# Calling oracle package/procedure using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oracle, entity-framework, stored-procedures

[Doing exactly the same in this LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21965605/how-to-call-a-stored-procedure-inside-an-oracle-package-with-entity-framework)

I am trying to call an Oracle procedure/package using Entity Framework. But I am getting a different error than the one mentioned in the link.

Code

```
public List<ClearTypes> GetOffices()
{
     var param1 = new OracleParameter("P_CUR", OracleDbType.RefCursor, ParameterDirection.Output);           
     var ATests = this.Database.SqlQuery<ClearTypes>("BEGIN PRC_GET_CLEAR(:P_CUR); end;", param1).ToList();            
     return ATests;
}
```

SQL query:

```
BEGIN
    OPEN P_CUR FOR

    SELECT ID, Name FROM ClearType;

END
```

`ClearType` class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MVCApp2.Models
{
    public class ClearTypes
    {
       public int ID{get;set;}
       public string Name{ get; set; }
    }
}
```

The error what I get when running the application is:

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
>   System.Data.Entity.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Value does not fall within the expected range.

What might be the reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This will work if you add Oracle managed data access package from
>   Nuget packages in Visual studio.

using `OracleParameter` from `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;` will not throw error.