# PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in stored procedure

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework

I used the Function Import to my EF model so I can execute a stored procedure. I did this for 3 SP and all working (without input parameter), but now I have one that I need it to receive a parameter:

```
public virtual ObjectResult<ClientDedication> GET_CLIENT_DEDICATION(string p_ANOMES)
        {
            var p_ANOMESParameter = p_ANOMES != null ?
                new ObjectParameter("P_ANOMES", p_ANOMES) :
                new ObjectParameter("P_ANOMES", typeof(string));

            return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<ClientDedication>("GET_CLIENTES_SEM_DEDICACAO", p_ANOMESParameter);
        }
```

But I keep gettinh this error, when I execut it:

> PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to

The SP on my DB receives a Varchar, and just 1 parameter, so everything should be fine.

My DB is oracle

Comment: Doesn't your stored procedure return cursor?

Comment: Yes. And I created a ComplexType. Could this error be from there?

Comment: Please check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22010087/1380428).

Comment: which part? the example is diferent from mine

Comment: You also have to add paremeter for cursor, like `new OracleParameter("result", OracleDbType.Cursor, ParameterDirection.Output);`

Comment: Not I get this error:
PL/SQL ORA-01008 : Not all variables bound

Comment: can you please replace `typeof(string)` with `DbNull.Value` and check

Comment: I wasn't passing the output parameter. That was my problem. Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: Just one question, I changed the method like you said on "Context.cs" file ut each time I change something on edmx file, also changes this method and have to do all over again. Isn't there a way to don't allow this?

Comment: @AndreRoque, please post another question for your new issue.